# LinkedHashMap and MapProperty

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am learning JavaFX and I am rewriting my application from Swing to JavaFX.

Now I am facing this problem.

In Swing I selected data from database, I saved them into ResultSet and from ResultSet I inserted them into LinkedHashMap.

From LinkedHashMap I inserted them into ComboBox in the same order.

The same order is important.

```
// Swing
private final LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
... // ResultSet
while(rs.next()){
        linkedHashMap.put(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
    }
... // ComboBox
Iterator it=linkedHashMap.values().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
        String value=(String)it.next();
        jComboBox.addItem(value);
    }
...
```

In JavaFX I rewrited LinkedHashMap into MapProperty but I do not know how I can hold data in the same order? After insert to ComboBox data are not in the same order.

```
// JavaFX
private final MapProperty<Integer, String> observableHashMap = new SimpleMapProperty<>(FXCollections.observableHashMap())
... // ResultSet
while(rs.next()){       
        observableHashMap.put(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
    }
... // ComboBox
this.getComboBox.getItems().clear();
this.getComboBox().getItems().addAll( observableHashMap.values() );
...
```

How can I hold data in MapProperty in the same order?

Does have sense use Property for data which I use for select only?

Comment: Why do you need the `MapProperty`? Can't you just use the `LinkedHashMap` like you did before?

Comment: Ok I will return back

Answer (score 0):

```
new SimpleMapProperty<>(FXCollections.observableMap(new LinkedHashMap<>()));
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and explain it in context of the question. Answers that contain only code are less useful to others looking at the question and, therefore, less likely to get upvotes.